# Who is Seyyed (سید)? (Shia view)

Tags: shiism, sayyid

As probably majority or even all of you are aware, (except the prefix name of Seyyed or Sayyid which means mister), there are many people (Muslims) who are named as Seyyed or Sayyid at the initial part of their names. (Commonly, at the initial part of their first name).

According to my average knowledge and also according to what I found during my researches, I figured out that Seyyed is related to the persons who are related to the grandfather of Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him and his household), and even I saw it is related to the Shia Imam’s descendent based on

- [f-sadat.persianblog.ir](http://f-sadat.persianblog.ir/tag/%D8%B3%DB%8C%D8%AF_%DA%A9%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%9F_%D8%B3%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%AA_%D8%A7%D8%B2_%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%AD%DB%8C%D9%87_%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%9F)

I am looking for a more authentic site in regard to the above mentioned matter. Well, more precise explanation concerning the mentioned matter would be appreciated.

*Note: I'm looking for a Shiite site(s) (which has elaborated it)*

Answer (score 3):

According to Shia Islam (and I assume likewise based on Sunni Islam), Sayyid or Seyyed (السید) were and are related to Haashem (the grandfather of the Prophet (peace be upon him and his household)… Nowadays, it is said to the children (and childrend of children …) of Imam Ali – Hazrat Fatimah-Zahra … as well.

**Related explanation:**

> Sayyid (also spelled , "Sayyed", "Saiyid","Seyd", "Syed", "Sayed"
>   "Seyed" and "Seyyed") (pronounced [ˈsæjjɪd], or [ˈsæjjed], Arabic:
>   سيد‎; meaning Mister) (plural Sadah Arabic: سادة‎, Sāda(h)) is an
>   honorific title denoting males accepted as descendants of the Islamic
>   Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him and his family) through his grandsons, Hasan ibn Ali and Husayn ibn
>   Ali, sons of Muhammad's daughter Fatimah and his son-in-law Ali (Ali
>   ibn Abi Talib).[1](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa9143) Conventionally, descent is patrilineal. However, in
>   1632 when an Ottoman court challenged a man wearing a sayyid's green
>   turban he established that he was a sayyid on his mother's side, and
>   this was accepted by the court.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sayyid):130
>
> Daughters of sayyids are given the titles Sayyida, Alawiyah, or
>   Sharifa. In some regions of the Islamic world, e.g., India, the
>   descendants of Muhammad are given the title Amir or Mir, meaning
>   "commander", "general", or "prince". Children of Sayyida mother but a
>   non Sayyid father are referred to as Mirza...

---

**Reference and further complete info:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa9143)
- [https://en.wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sayyid)

Comment: Nicely explained,Sunnis also consider the same as family of Syeddah Fatima Zahra RadiaAllahu anha and Syeddina  Mawla Ali RadiAllahu anhu and their decendents to be Syed.Well my family is Hussaini Syed.JazakAllah for this question and nice answer.

Comment: Hussaini Syed? Really? oops, fantastic. Good for you. Hopefully you appreciate this nice position...  Good luck.